# Performing geo.intersects Filter in Azure Search on a SubEntity That is a Collection

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to apply a geo.intersects filter to a search query in Azure Search but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

I tried the following...

```
$filter=Location/any(loc: geo.intersects(loc, geography'POLYGON((-122.031577 47.578581, -122.031577 47.678581, -122.131577 47.678581, -122.031577 47.578581)))')
```

Getting this error...

```
"Invalid expression: ')' or ',' expected at position 152 in 'Location/any(loc: geo.intersects(loc, geography'POLYGON((-122.031577 47.578581, -122.031577 47.678581, -122.131577 47.678581, -122.031577 47.578581)))')'.\r\nParameter name: $filter"
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced the final single quote. It's supposed to close the polygon literal, which has two sets of parens. Try this:

```
$filter=Location/any(loc: geo.intersects(loc, geography'POLYGON((-122.031577 47.578581, -122.031577 47.678581, -122.131577 47.678581, -122.031577 47.578581))'))
```

The final quote closes the polygon, the next paren closes `geo.intersects`, and the final paren closes `any`.

The error message included a position at which the syntax error was detected (152 in this case). Note that the position counts from the beginning of the filter expression itself, which doesn't include `$filter=`.